# domain account vs user account

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to retrieve `ObjectSID` for a logged in user using LDAP. The problem is that it works for an admin account but not for my local NT account. I am trying to figure out the difference between the two. I did some research and based on my understanding, I believe `ObjectSID` is an user attribute and hence it won't be present for a domain account. (here my NT account) So how can I convert my NT account to a user account? Should I add it to certain groups in AD? I am a newbie when it comes to LDAP/AD

After debugging the code, I noticed it returns only domain attributes(using `Scope.BASE`) for my NT account and user attributes(using `Scope.SUBTREE`) for my Admin account.

My PC/NT account is part of a domain group.

Answer (score 0):

A local account like your NT account is NOT an Active Directory or LDAP domain account. Therefore you can't obtain a domain SID for this user object. You can however make an AD user member of your local administrator group, which should already be the case, if the computer is member of this AD. Then the domain admins should also be members of local admins and should return the SID.

Comment: How does it return domain attributes if my NT account is NOT a domain account?

Comment: It doesn't, since as you already pointed out, it's not a domain account, and therefore doesn't possess domain attributes. If you don't have access to a domain admin account, make your domain user account member of local admins and try with this. Then, I advise you to deactivate the local admin account and only use your domain user account for administrative tasks. Why working with a local account if your computer is member of a domain?